# Dash: Fit a dropdown and graph in an inline-block

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash, dashboard

I want to plot 4 graphs side-by-side in the style of a 2x2 grid. The graph in the lower right corner I want to attach a dropdown to with a callback that allows for changing the color.

I have an example of it below. However, the issue is that I have to explicitly set the width, otherwise the graph wont display. Am I doing this correctly?

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objects as go

app = Dash(__name__)


f1 = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=["a", "b", "c"], y=[2, 3, 1], marker_color="Gold"))
f2 = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=["a", "b", "c"], y=[2, 3, 1], marker_color="Gold"))
f3 = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=["a", "b", "c"], y=[2, 3, 1], marker_color="Gold"))
f4 = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=["a", "b", "c"], y=[2, 3, 1], marker_color="Gold"))


app.layout = html.Div([
        html.Div([dcc.Graph(id="1", figure=f1)], style={'display': 'inline-block'}),
        html.Div([dcc.Graph(id="2", figure=f2)], style={'display': 'inline-block'}),
        html.Div([dcc.Graph(id="3", figure=f3)], style={'width': '37%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
        html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="dropdown",
            options=["Gold", "MediumTurquoise", "LightGreen"],
            value="Gold",
            clearable=False), dcc.Graph(id="4", figure=f4)], style={'width': '37%', 'display': 'inline-block'})])
    

@app.callback(
    Output("4", "figure"),
    Input("dropdown", "value"),
)
def display_color(color):
    fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=["a", "b", "c"], y=[2, 3, 1], marker_color=color))
    return fig


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mainly a HTML/CSS problem. I'm not an expert here but you could create a simple "grid" by wrapping every row with an `html.Div` and styling the elements (columns) via `{'width': '50%', 'display': 'inline-block'}`. For the second row, second column, you have to wrap the dropdown and the graph into an additional `html.Div` which gets the 50% width.

Here is the code for the layout:

```py
block_column_50_style = {'width': '50%', 'display': 'inline-block'}

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Graph(id="1", figure=f1, style=block_column_50_style),
            dcc.Graph(id="2", figure=f2, style=block_column_50_style)
        ]
    ),
    html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Graph(id="3", figure=f3, style=block_column_50_style),
            html.Div(
                [
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id="dropdown",
                        options=["Gold", "MediumTurquoise", "LightGreen"],
                        value="Gold",
                        clearable=False),
                    dcc.Graph(id="4", figure=f4)
                ],
                style=block_column_50_style
            )
        ]
    )
])
```

And a screenshot of the page:

[image]

P.S. If you don't want to create this grid yourself, I can recommend using [Dash Bootstrap Components](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/) which has an [API for using Bootstrap's grid layout](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/layout/). This will make it easier :)